# Brother MFC-2700DW scan from printer results in "Check Connection"

Tags: linux-mint, scanner, brother

I have a Brother MFC-2700DW printer connected to my Linux Mint 20 machine over WiFi. Printing and scanning from the computer work fine after following the instructions on Brother's website. However, trying to scan from the printer yields a "Check connection" error. I have the latest drivers and brscan-skey installed. Running

```
brscan-skey -l
```

is successful, in this case returning

```
MFC2700DW         : brother4:net1;dev0  : 192.168.1.32         Active
```

Does anyone have a solution?